# recursive ceiling java

Tags: java, recursion

This is a homework question, so a basic recursive algorithm is all I'm really after. I am working on floor/ceiling methods for an AATree. My current tree has this structure:

```
        40
  20        60
10  30    50    80
              70  90
                    100
```

(Level Order). I have an iterative solution for my floor method:

```
 /**
   * Returns the greatest element in the set <= the_target.
   * Strings are compared by ASCII values.
   * 
   * @param the_target Element to compare set values with.
   * @return Greatest element <= the_target, null if no such element exists.
   */
  public E floor(final E the_target) {
    AANode<E> current_node = my_root;
    E result = null;
    int root_value = compare(current_node.my_element, the_target);
    while (true) {
      if (root_value == 0) {
        if (current_node.my_left.equals(my_null_node) 
            && current_node.my_right.equals(my_null_node)) {
          break;
        }
        result = current_node.my_element;
        break;
      }
      if (contains(the_target)) {
        result = the_target;
        break;
      } else if (root_value > 0) { 
        if (current_node.my_left.my_element == null) {
          break;
        }
        current_node = current_node.my_left;
        root_value = compare(current_node.my_element, the_target);
      } else {
        if (current_node.my_right.my_element == null) {
          result = current_node.my_element;
          break;
        }
        result = current_node.my_element; 
        current_node = current_node.my_right;  
        root_value = compare(current_node.my_element, the_target);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

But I want to make my ceiling() method recursive. It has to have this method signature:

```
  /**
   * Returns the smallest element in the set >= the_target.
   * 
   * @param the_target Element to compare set values with.
   * @return Smallest element >= the_target, null if no such element exists.
   */
  public E ceiling(final E the_target);
```

and I was going to implement this using a helper recursive method that returns E. I am trying to get my logic right and would love some algorithm suggestions.

Thanks everyone for your help! I got it.

```
 /**
   * Helper recursive method for ceiling().
   * 
   * @param the_root The current node.
   * @param the_smallest The previous smallest element.
   * @param the_target The target for ceiling.
   * @return The ceiling element of the tree.
   */
  private E findCeiling(final AANode<E> the_root, final AANode<E> the_smallest,
                        final E the_target) {
    AANode<E> small = the_smallest;
    if (compare(the_target, small.my_element) > 0) {
      small = the_root;
    }
    // base case
    if (the_root.my_left.my_element == null 
        && the_root.my_right.my_element == null) {
      return small.my_element;
    } else {
      if (compare(the_target, the_root.my_element) > 0) {
        if (compare(the_smallest.my_element, the_root.my_element) > 0) {
          small = the_root;
        }
        return findCeiling(the_root.my_right, small, the_target);
      } else {
        if (compare(the_smallest.my_element, the_root.my_element) > 0) {
          small = the_root;
        }
        return findCeiling(the_root.my_left, small, the_target);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: unless your class assignment states that you must use recursion, both of these are better solved with a simple loop.  In general, I view recursion as a terrible solution to any problem.

Comment: Have you taken a crack at it yet?

Comment: Im working on it again right now, more to come ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to traverse the tree and keep track of the smallest value in the set seen so far that is less than target.  Lets call this value `SGT`

Your helper routine needs to take in the current node being examined, and the current `SGT` value.

Here's a hint to get you started...

```
 public E ceiling(final E target) { 
     return ceilingHelper(root, root.my_element, target);
 }

 private E ceilingHelper(final AANode<E> current_node, 
                         final E SGT, 
                         final E target) { 
    //now do you get the idea ?  your recursion will need a base case
    //and a recursive step.  you can traverse the tree using a depth first
    //search
 }
```

Comment: Thats helpful. I was heading in that direction but with the method signature: E findCeiling(AANode<E> the_root, E the_smallest, E the_target, boolean the_found);

Answer (score 0):

I don't think providing an exact solution would be appropriate but you should look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal. There are all the general algorithms you need to do this recursively.

Generally the recursive solution involves defining the problem as a subproblem. As a hint, how  are the ceils of two neighboring subtrees related? Also think about what the basecase would be where recursion ends. What is the ceil of a leaf node?

Recursive solutions for tree problems can be very very concise and simple.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I wasnt looking for an answer, so this is helpful.

Comment: FYI, the acceptable type of help I can receive is basic logic and higher level abstraction